Jupyterlab alternative for pdb/ipdb
How can I set a breakpoint in a Python script running in a Jupyter notebook such that:

When the breakpoint is hit, the variables from the script are available in the Jupyter kernel.
I can interact with and modify those variables in the Jupyter notebook during the pause.
After resuming execution, the changes I made in the notebook are reflected in the script's state.

The typical import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace() approach doesn't allow direct synchronization of the kernel's namespace with the script. Is there an alternative that provides this functionality?

Can you say more about this third bullet point? I'm not quite following what you seek there. Maybe an example would help? For the first two bullet points, you can use  from IPython import embed; embed() in the Python script where you want the breakpoint. Then run the script with %run my_script.py in the notebook. Or perhaps importantly in your case, use %run -i my_script.py to run it interactively in the notebook kernel; see here about the -i interactive flag for %run.  After executing the script and ...

 hitting the breakpoint, you can view what variables currently are by typing them in the prompt, since it is IPython, and hitting enter. You can reassign them at this point, too. Then when you are done, you can enter exit in the prompt to resume the script running. See twitter.com/choldgraf/status/972877872502312962 and here for more information.
